# nested select query more efficient

Tags: mysql

Am having `user` & `user_code` table having one to many relationship. Please find the below table structure.

User table

```
 id email   username    date
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
679 test@test.com   sathis  4/20/2019 9:04
680 test@test.com   ram 4/20/2019 9:04
680 test@test.com   ram 4/20/2019 9:04
680 test@test.com   ram 4/20/2019 9:04
681 test@test.com   Steve   4/20/2019 9:04
681 test@test.com   Steve   4/20/2019 9:04
681 test@test.com   Steve   4/20/2019 9:04
681 test@test.com   Steve   4/20/2019 9:04
681 test@test.com   Steve   4/20/2019 9:04
```

User_Code table

```
user_id code
679 J039
679 J080
679 J320
679 J54L
679 K31P
679 L05C
679 T030
679 V150
680 J039
680 J080
680 J320
681 ABC12
681 CD123
681 opo123
681 qw123
681 ieu12
```

if i give the `username` (from user table) then it should check for the `code` (from user_code table) and the same code should check whether it is presented for some other `user_id`(from user_code table) and should return that `user_id`s also.

for example.

```
  id    username
679 sathis
680 ram
```

from the above table, if i get `sathis` as input. i should get `ram` as output results.
 Because `Sathis's` code also presented for `Ram` also.

Please find my sql nested query below

```
select id,username from users
where 
id in (
select user_id from user_code
where
code in (
select code from user_code
where user_id = ( select id from user where username = 'sathis')))
```

How can i simplify this query more efficient,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for improve performance you could avoid IN clause and use inner join on subquery

```
select id, username 
from users 
inner join (
  select distinct user_id 
  from User_Code 
  inner join  (
    select code 
    from User_Code 
    inner join User ON User_Code.user_id = user.id
    where  username = 'sathis'
  ) t on t.code = User_Code.code
) t2 on t2.user_id = users.id
```

Comment: its not check with the `code` from user_code table., its just printing only `Sathis's` record. it should bring `Ram` also.

Comment: show me the error .. .. answer  updated . removing a wrong . (dot)

Comment: Query is working., but its not giving `Ram's` record., it should bring. because both `Sathis` & `Ram` having same `code` in `user_code` table.

Comment: `  inner join User ON code.user_id = user.id` in this line code.user_id - code is object of table `user_code` ?